# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I just arrived at this site recently, and my first impression is that you aren't really interested in helping people, and that you don't appreciate a good question.  I asked a question that was fairly general and something that might be fairly straightforward for an experienced computer science researcher to address.  I was told that my question was not adequate, had the title modified so that that the original meaning of the question was changed, and told that I needed to do more research.  Not a single hint at what keyword to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Counting elements that are greater than the median of medians](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19542/counting-elements-that-are-greater-than-the-median-of-medians)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What can Idris not do by giving up Turing completeness?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19577/what-can-idris-not-do-by-giving-up-turing-completeness)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [In type systems, is there a name for SQL's way of cutting and combining record types into new types?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19134/in-type-systems-is-there-a-name-for-sqls-way-of-cutting-and-combining-record-t)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Reduce variant of Vertex Cover to original decision-version Vertex cover problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18997/reduce-variant-of-vertex-cover-to-original-decision-version-vertex-cover-problem)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Which algorithms can not be parallelized?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/which-algorithms-can-not-be-parallelized)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [how to solve this lambda expression with free variable/s](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19204/how-to-solve-this-lambda-expression-with-free-variable-s)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [P vs NP: Assuming P = NP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19328/p-vs-np-assuming-p-np)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Language where every prefix has almost equal a's and b's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19073/language-where-every-prefix-has-almost-equal-as-and-bs)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18938/what-abbreviations-to-use-in-cs-citations

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [Constructing inequivalent binary matrices](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19250/constructing-inequivalent-binary-matrices)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 9)

---

Comment: I am quite satisfied with this sample. Among the lowest scoring questions, one has since been closed (and should probably have been earlier) and the other simply has no good *answer* yet (the problem seems to be tough), which is not per se a bad thing.

Comment: I wonder why several of these yielded large numbers of both Excellent and Needs Improvement.  Does this indicate disagreement about how well the answers to those questions compare to other web resources or what constitutes a web resource, or does this simply indicate differences in Google-fu?  After all, the assessment is meant to be in comparison with other web resources.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon, would you like to pick one question where the results surprised you and dig into it in depth?  For instance, we could look at "P vs NP: Assuming P = NP".  For that one, maybe some reviewers were unaware that the question is already answered on the Wikipedia page on NP-completeness, whereas others were already familiar with resources where this is answered.  Or were you thinking of a different one?